# Accessing content of child nodes from SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having trouble accessing the child nodes of my SimpleXML content. I've tried a few variations like `$xmlData->id` or `$xmlData['id']`.

I'm somewhat new to this area, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code sample:

```
    $xmlData = simplexml_load_string($string);
    $person = $xmlData->documentElement;
    $id = $xmlData->id;
```

Var dump of `$xmlData` from Simple XML:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#23 (10) { 
     ["id"]=> string(10) "yTZn1JIaaa" 
     ["first-name"]=> string(6) "First Name" 
     ["last-name"]=> string(6) "Last Name"...
```

Comment: What is the error message? And which child nodes are you asking about?

Comment: Hm, seems `->id` should work... What is your input XML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [display data from XML using php simplexml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833788/display-data-from-xml-using-php-simplexml)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to rebuild your snippet:

```
<?php
$string = "<person><id>1</id><firstname>Foo</firstname><lastname>Bar</lastname></person>";
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xmlData->id . " - " . $xmlData->firstname . " - " . $xmlData->lastname;
?>
```

This worked fine for me - the Output was:

```
1 - Foo - Bar
```

You can see, that my firstname and lastname tagnames are different to yours - the dash sometimes causes troubles. If you need the dash, do it this way instead:

```
echo $xmlData->id . " - " . $xmlData->{'first-name'} . " - " . $xmlData->{'last-name'};
```

Anyways, the `id` worked fine...so maybe you have another error that prevents your scripts from running properly? Maybe it would be helpful if you could post your XML-String.

Cheers,
Max

P.S.: Why are you executing this line?

```
$person = $xmlData->documentElement;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes the dash was problematic. The {'a'} makes method sense. Everything works now.I originally didn't have the $person =  line in the code, but after looking at some more examples tried it. Of course, didn't help.

Comment: @jsuissa technically, this answer is the same as the code you claim doesnt work. can you please point out what the exact problem was that made it now work now all of sudden?

Comment: Sure -- it seems that without the surrounding brackets just having $xmlData->first-name failed, but with {'first-name'} like that it worked. I'm not sure why myself. Wondering if this could be related to using Codeigniter?

Comment: @jsuissa no, thats because PHP will interpret $xmlData->first-name as $xmlData->first - name, e.g. it will try to subtract. Hyphens are not valid variables name and if you encounter them in XML you have to use the curly brace syntax. Your question did ask for the id element though and not for the hyphenated elements. Please try to be more specific next time.